# how to compare and check if string is entered in number field in sql

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I was making page validation in oracle apex. I just had a confusion that how can I check if user is entering string in number field.
I was doing like this:

```
if :P2_SAL > 85000  then
return 'Salary must be less THAN 85K';
else if :P2_SAL <> NUMBER then
return 'please enter salary in digits';
ELSE RETURN NULL;
end if;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Oracle APEX 5, there is a standard validation to check if a value is a number:

[image]

Comment: Yes i know that but i am not doing it for each and every items.I am doing it for the whole page using  function returning error text option.

Comment: You don't need to. By defining your field as a Number item, the validation is inherent.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions might help here, something like

```
if not regexp_like(:P2_SAL, '^\d+$') then
   return 'Please enter salary in digits';
end if;
```